# The different contents of Docker -v result in different effects after container startup

Tags: docker

There is a problem using `-v "%desktopPath%\%folderName%":/dobot/userdata/project:rw`, it will report that the file `/dobot/userdata/project/properties/controlCabType.json` does not exist, and there is no problem using `-v "%desktopPath%\%folderName%":/dobot/userdata/project/project:rw`.
This file `/dobot/userdata/project/properties/controlCabType.json` was generated during the creation of container images `dobotv4vc:v4510b2`. When executing `docker run`, the same container image is used, with only a difference after the `-v` option.
I have added `rw` permissions to the shared directory, but there is still a problem. What is the problem?

My container image is based on Debian:bookworm, and my hosting system is Windows 10.

Docker run complete instruction:

```
docker run --dns=8.8.8.8 -d --name=crv4 --network bridge ^
    -p 2022:22 -p 2502:502 -p 2503:503 -p 1502:1502 -p 1503:1503     -p 18083:8083    -p 18883:1883 ^
    -p 22000:22000 -p 22001:22001  -p 29999:29999  -p 30004:30004  -p 30005:30005  -p 30006:30006 ^
    -p 40001:40001 -p 40002:40002  -p 40003:40003  -p 40004:40004  -p 40005:40005  -p 40006:40006 ^
    -p 65501:65501 -p 65502:65502  -p 65503:65503  -p 65504:65504  -p 65505:65505  -p 65506:65506 ^
    -p 65511:65511 -p 65512:65512  -p 65513:65513  -p 65514:65514  -p 65515:65515  -p 65516:65516 ^
    -p 65521:65521 -p 65522:65522  -p 65523:65523  -p 65524:65524  -p 65525:65525  -p 65526:65526 ^
    -p 65527:65527  -v "%desktopPath%\%folderName%":/dobot/userdata/project:rw    dobotv4vc:v4510b2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
-v "%desktopPath%\%folderName%":/dobot/userdata/project:rw
```

the `/dobot/userdata/project` directory inside the running container provides access to `%desktopPath%\%folderName%` on the host. If the program running inside the container expects to find `/dobot/userdata/project/properties/controlCabType.json`, then that file needs to be present in `%desktopPath%\%folderName%\properties` on the host. You mention that the file was generated during the creation of the container image; by mounting a volume on `/dobot/userdata/project`, you’re masking that file in the image.

With

```
-v "%desktopPath%\%folderName%":/dobot/userdata/project/project:rw
```

the volume is mounted on `/dobot/userdata/project/project`, and `/dobot/userdata/project` itself still provides access to the files in the container image (apart from anything under the `project` directory there).

Comment: When creating the image, doesn't `controllCabType.json` already exist in the image? `docker run` is just starting the container, should this file be generated again? I understand a bit, but not very clearly.

Comment: When I first create file `controllCabType.json` externally and then execute dockerfile to generate the image, there is still a problem.